# Is a reader feminine like the moon or ship?

Tags: nouns, gender

Is a ***reader*** feminine like the *moon* or a *ship*? Here I present a few examples from an academic lecture on how to write a good scientific paper. The audience are aspiring authors of future scientific papers. The lecturer always refers to the author as "he" and to the reader as "she". The lecturer uses this gender differentiation repeatedly and subconsciously. The audience swallows this convention naturally just like pelican swallows fish.

***"He** positions the reader so **she** can see it with **her** own eyes."*
https://youtu.be/OV5J6BfToSw?t=528

*"The reader can see it for **herself**."*
https://youtu.be/OV5J6BfToSw?t=719

*"Now, the problem with writing in clichés is that it either forces the reader to shut down **her** visual brain (...)
or if **she** actually does think through the prose to the underlying image, **she** will inevitably be upended by the mixed metaphors."*
https://youtu.be/OV5J6BfToSw?t=1074

It's obvious that the lecturer does not imply that all authors of scientific papers are men and all readers are women.

I am sure it is not the first time I heard the convention of referring to reader as female. Here is another example:

*"Tell your reader just enough to make **her** care about your main character, then get to the the problem, the quest, the challenge, the danger—whatever it is that drives your story."*
https://jerryjenkins.com/how-to-write-short-stories/

Hence my question. Is is a common case that writers refer to their audience reader as female similarly like lots of us do with the moon, or a ship?

Comment: Nouns (such as the moon) do not usually have a gender in English. The lecturer is referring to the reader as "she" but I have not watched through to see if he has mentioned a specific reader. If not, he could have said "he" or "she" or "they" but *chose* to say "she" to refer to an unspecified person. Some decades ago it would always be "he" and when that became unsustainable some people began to say "she" and others began to say "they". It is quite acceptable now to say "they" in the singular to refer to an unspecified person.

Comment: So what makes you think "she" is wrong?

Comment: @WeatherVane why wrong? It is easy to look up that moon is she, sun is he. It is easy to check that in fary-tales a mouse is he. And when you speak about ship it is she. That is why I ask about reader.

Comment: Do you think all scientists are men? That kind of thinking is why many writers have abandoned the convention of referring to unknown people as "he"

Comment: The speaker may have chosen to use different genders so they could use pronouns for both without ambiguity, rather than having to repeatedly clarify the antecedent of “he” (or “she”) for both.

Comment: Ships and other nouns do not have a gender, although they might be talked about as if they do, for example a **man-of-war**.

Comment: @WeatherVane Man-of-war ships are famine, at least for marines and for Wikipedia. Example: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HMS_Constant_Warwick_(1645)

Comment: No, **nouns have no gender** in English. Please ask this on a politics or interpersonal site. From [here](https://www.theguardian.com/notesandqueries/query/0,5753,-15935,00.html), *This sexist practice may be dying out especially among people who actually use ships. I hope so. I heard a few years ago a radio interview with the pilot of a hovercraft. The interviewer persistently referred to the vessel as "she". The pilot just as persistently referred to it as "it".*

Comment: It is an exception, not proof. There are tones of works why anthropomorphism emerges. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0,5&qsp=1&q=brand+personification&qst=ib  Whenever something saves life it becomes more then it. So is the course with ships, swords, airplanes. If that is good or bad, it is not my question. I just ask if "reader" shares the honor of a "ship".

Comment: As stated in my first comment, when it became unsustainable to refer to individuals in a mixed audience as "he" some people started to say "she". It does not imply that they are all female. It is politics.

Answer (score 4):

No.

An author, when speaking about their "reader" may choose to use any of "he", "she", "he or she" or (more commonly) "they".

The moon is also not feminine. Although sometimes authors may choose to personify the moon as feminine. This is poetry, not grammar. In European cultures, if the moon is personified, it is personified as a woman.

Nouns in English, even nouns like "girl" or "man" do not have grammatical gender.  Nouns like "reader" and "moon" certainly do not have gender.

Comment: I know that I may choose to personify my ship as he, but most people personify ships as female. I am asking if it is a common convention that people refer to reader as "her".

Comment: No, it isn't. On the 'short story' site, the writer has used _his_ a few sentences earlier. He is evidently choosing to vary the gender of the hypothetical reader.

Comment: @Przemyslaw Remin: Don't assume there's any particular significance to the fact that you've found one context where someone decided to use ***he*** for the author and ***she*** for the reader. That would almost certainly have been an entirely arbitrary choice, where the primary purpose was simply to "set the stage" so that all future references to the author and reader using ***pronouns*** would be unambiguous. Nothing to do with there being any kind of "default gender" for the real-world referents.

Comment: " if it is a common convention that people refer to reader as "her".  "  My answer stands unchanged: No.  An author may choose to use "he" or "she"  or "he or she" or "they".  There is no convention to refer to readers as "she"

Comment: This answer misses the distinction between he/she used to refer to an inanimate object, and generic he/she as a pronoun referring to a person of unspecified gender.